# Execute a http request response in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, http, request

I have an http request which delivers 'JSON.stringify(data)'.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/api/hello", true);
xhr.send(); 
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
};
```

How can I run the code and print the contents of data?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Do you want to parse JSON in your handler? Does `xhr.responseText` literally contain `JSON.stringify(data)`  (which most certainly would indicate a server-side programming error)? Is there some code missing from your example that you refer to?

Answer (score 0):

your code should be working, the endpoint may be the problem, check the url your trying to get into the endpoint from, then don't forget to check the readyState and the status of your request before doing nothing.

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
    {
       console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
```